# Richtig oder falsch: "keine" oder "nicht"

Tags: verb, question

Welcher Satz ist richtig und warum?

"Ich lerne nicht Deutsch" oder "Ich lerne kein Deutsch"?

Comment: Beides ist richtig: So zählt der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch) beide Varianten in seinen Beispielen auf: `sie kann, lehrt, lernt, schreibt, spricht, versteht [kein, nicht, gut, schlecht] Deutsch`

Comment: @tofro Die verlinkte Frage ist auf Englisch. Es ist nicht selbstverständlich, dass jemand, der hier auf Deutsch fragt, die dortigen Antworten versteht.

Comment: @Matthias Dann ist es m. A. nach sinnvoll, dass er ebendort nach einer Erläuterung auf deutsch nachfragt - Es ist nicht sinnvoll, jede Frage und jede Antwort in jede Sprache zu duplizieren.

Comment: @tofro Das wurde schon mal auf Meta diskutiert: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/809/9091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind richtig, sind aber grammatikalisch leicht unterschiedlich aufgebaut. In

> Ich lerne nicht Deutsch.

bezieht sich die Verneinung auf das Prädikat, also auf die Tätigkeit des Lernens. In

> Ich lerne kein Deutsch.

bezieht sich die Verneinung auf das Objekt "Deutsch".

Wenn man die Sätze etwas ausbaut, wird der Unterschied deutlicher:

> Ich lerne nicht Deutsch, sondern ich spreche es bereits.
>
> Ich lerne kein Deutsch, sondern Französisch.

Comment: Wäre der erste Fall nicht eher *Ich lerne Deutsch nicht, sondern ich spreche es bereits*? Ist der Satz *Ich lerne nicht Deutsch, sondern Französisch* nicht auch richtig?

Comment: "Ich lerne kein Deutsch, ich kann es nämlich schon" ist auch richtig.

Comment: Das die Fälle austauschbar sind, heißt nicht, dass die Antwort nicht richtig ist. Ich empfinde den Unterschied genauso: das "nicht" bezieht sich auf das Prädikat, wohingegen das "kein" aufs Objekt bezogen ist.